# Неправильно указывается тип input при создании формы Django

Tags: python, django

Файл models.py

```
class Game(models.Model):
gameName = models.CharField(max_length=256)
gameDate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=True)
gamePlace = models.CharField(max_length=256)
gameResultPlace = models.IntegerField()
gameResultPoints = models.IntegerField()
```

Файл views.py

```
def index(request):
form = GameAddForm(request.POST or None)

if request.method == "POST":
    print(form)

return render(request, 'gameAdder/gameAdder.html', locals())
```

Когда генерируется страница,то тип input gameDate почему то становится 'text'.В чем может быть проблема?По заданию человек должен сам указывать дату и время игры.

Comment: Как написано в документации (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/), `The default form widget for this field is a single TextInput`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class GameAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Game
        exclude = []
        widgets = {
            'gameDate': forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'}),
        }
```

P.S. Соблюдайте [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) и не передавайте `locals` в качестве контекста.

Comment: Спасибо большое,так работает)

Comment: @ДанилаКононихин [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).